# Django filter applied when kwargs else return all

Tags: django, django-models, django-generic-views

I would like to display list of all **Team** objects or narrow to only those related to **country** passed via kwarg parameter.

```
class TeamListView(ListView):
    """View to display all or filtered teams."""
    model = Team

    def get_queryset(self):
        filters = {}
        country = self.kwargs['country'] if 'country' in self.kwargs else None
        filters.update({ 'country': country })
        return super(TeamListView, self).get_queryset() \
            .filter(**filters)
```

I can easilly achieve filtering but for no parameter instead of all objects I get None.

Of course I know, I can return *super()...all()* instead of *filter()* but that looks ugly and I'm asking if there's any magic keyword like `__all__` or I should give some Q object but how to prepare it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
class TeamListView(ListView):
    """View to display all or filtered teams."""
    model = Team

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = super().get_queryset()
        if 'country' in self.kwargs:
            return qs.filter(country=self.kwargs['country'])
        return qs  # 🖘 otherwise return the entire queryset
```

Comment: Yes, that looks very good! 

I could now add other `if`s below to filter out other things and the result will be chained.
Of course I would change this first `return` to `=` and work on this queryset.
Thanks!